# Multidimensional array search using another element value

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array built dynamically. 
Is it possible to get the value of an element by using another element.

e.g : search with idQ = 26 and get in return value its neighbor element values like :: idA=>49 and A=>500-10000

```
[0]=>
    array(5) {
        ["idQA"]=>
        string(3) "194"
        ["idQ"]=>
        string(2) "26"
        ["Q"]=>
        string(58) "Imposition supérieur
        à&nbsp; 2500€ d’impôts annuel"
        ["idA"]=>
        string(2) "49"
        ["A"]=>
        string(10) "5000-10000"
    }
[1]=>
    array(5) {
        ["idQA"]=>
        string(3) "173"
        ["idQ"]=>
        string(2) "22"
        ["Q"]=>
        string(20) "Si oui, laquelle(s):"
        ["idA"]=>
        string(2) "32"
        ["A"]=>
        string(7) "Voiture"
    }
```

Example array :: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9234703

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like:

```
$founded = 0;

foreach($my_array[1] as $key => $val) {

  if ($val == "something_to_search") {
    $founded = $key;
    break;
  }
}

$before = $my_array[1][$founded-1];
$after = $my_array[1][$founded+1];
```